# auth0 lock authenticated event not firing

Tags: ionic2, auth0

I am using auth0 lock for login in ionic2 application. But It's lock.on('authenticated') event is not firing. Neither that not authorization_error event is firing.

any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For callback redirection when I omitted redirect URL in options object, event started to trigger.